# Having custom year, not calendar year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like the year to begin from `August` and end in the following `July`. Is there a simple way of doing this apart from writing the ugly `IFELSE` statements that I will have to write for each year? Ideally, I'd like to have year like `2009-10`, `2010-11` etc. I'm using `Postgres`.

Here's an example query that I'd like to manipulate in order to get the custom year.

```
Select extract(year from created) as Year, type, count(*) 
from table
group by Year, type
order by Year
```

Any help would be appreciated, TIA.

Answer (score 3):

Consider setting up a Dates table. With this Dates table, you can associate a variety of data with each date, such as fiscal year, quarter, month #, whether it's a holiday, weekend, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (EXTRACT(month FROM created) > 6) THEN CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM created) AS text) || '-' || CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM created) +1 AS text) ELSE (CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM created) - 1 AS text) || '-' || CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM created) AS text)) END) AS CustomYear
FROM asmt.testscores order by created desc LIMIT 10000
```

This seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    extract(year from created + interval '6 months') as "Year",
    type,
    count(*) 
from table
group by 1, 2
order by 1
```